# Instantiation failure caused by function value with approximate constraint

Tags: go, generics

```
func GAddAll[E int, S ~[]E](e E, s S) S {
   copyS := make(S, len(s))
   for i, v := range s {
   copyS[i] = v + e
   }
   return copyS
}
```

For the above code, if I instantiate it like this, it will give an error when running(cannot infer S)

```
b := GAddAll[int]
fmt.Printf("%v", b(3, []int{1, 2}))
```

But it works fine like this

```
fmt.Printf("%v", GAddAll[int](3, []int{1, 2}))
```

I want to know why.

Comment: Because the compiler is not "smart enough" to infer the types in the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiation fails because `S ~[]E` has an approximate constraint, and there isn't enough type information to instantiate `S`.

When you assign the function value with:

```
b := GAddAll[int]
```

the function is already being instantiated. Quoting the spec:

> A generic function that is is **not called** requires a type argument list for instantiation; **if the list is partial, all remaining type arguments must be inferrable.**

However `S` isn't inferrable. The only information available to the compiler is the type parameter `E`. After a first pass of substitution, the compiler is **only able to infer the constraint `~[]E`**, which is now `~[]int`, but the type argument `S` is still unknown.

Given that approximate type sets with tilde (`~`) are virtually infinite, there's no way to conclusively determine what `S` is — it could be `type FooSlice []int` — and instantiation fails.

So if you need to pass around the function value, you must instantiate by supplying both type parameters:

```
b := GAddAll[int, []int] // ok
fmt.Printf("%v", b(3, []int{1, 2}))
```

Instead with the call expression:

```
GAddAll[int](3, []int{1, 2})
```

the compiler still can't infer `S` from the *type* argument `int`, but it can infer it from the *non-type* argument `[]int{1,2}`, and then instantiate the function.

> A generic function **that is called** may provide a (possibly partial) type argument list, or may omit it entirely **if the omitted type arguments are inferrable from the ordinary (non-type) function arguments**.

As a clarification, if you were to remove the tilde from the `S ~[]E`, like this:

```
func GAddAll[E int, S []E](e E, s S) S {}
```

inference would succeed by supplying only `E`, because the type set of `S`'s constraint would have cardinality 1 (an exact type).